# bbPress Topics not displaying

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

I have a bbPress installed in a custom theme built by someone, I tried to install bbPress and have created a few topics but it shows something different

It says that forum contains 4 topics but on the next line it shows No topics were found?
here is the live URL to see:
http://www.pdpeurope.ch/intranet/forums/forum/test-topic/

Thanks for helping in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can check and see if creating a bbpress.php file would solve the issue.

https://codex.bbpress.org/theme-compatibility/getting-started-in-modifying-the-main-bbpress-template/